# PHP remote project and subversion

Tags: php, svn

I am working on a live remote php project in eclipse.  ie, I just connect the the project using RSE edit the files and save.

I have recently setup subeclipse and am wondering if there is an way to add my php files to a subversion project while still working on the live project?  Or maybe there is a better way to do this and get the same result.

Comment: Are you the only person working on this project? Do you mean with "live" that the website is up and running and users are using it?

Comment: Yes, it is my website and only I am working on it right now.  By live, I mean the running website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the live version as the subversion repository directly but a common approach is, that you run a [Subversion Post-Commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) whenever you commit to your repository. The hook is just a basic shell or batch script that gets executed after a certain event. In this hook you export the current revision from the repository to the live system. In this case, if you commit errors into subversion you will have the errors in the live system right away which might be dangerous.

The alternative would be to use a build tool like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) which does the deployment of the application from the repository for you.

Comment: Would you prefer hooks over ant?

Comment: I would prefer ant, because you are working on a live system and you don't always want to update everything live whenever you check into subversion. And you can run the ant script as a post-commit hook too.